# core dumped when printing an array

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, 32-bit

In the following NASM code I want to print the second number in array1 to screen:

```
section .data:
  array1: db 1, 2, 3, 4 
section .text
  GLOBAL main

main:
  push ebp
  mov ebp, esp                                   

  add byte[array1+1], 30h  ;print the array1
  mov eax, 4
  mov ebx, 1
  mov ecx,  [array1+1]
  mov edx, 1
  int 80h

  mov esp, ebp
  pop ebp
  ret
```

The codes is simple enough, but terminal print the error message:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What's wrong?

@Michael Petch

Comment: The write syscall expects a pointer. Use `lea ecx, [array1+1]` instead of `mov`. PS: the C calling convention mandates `ebx` to be preserved.

Comment: @Jester The damned assistant forbids us from calling any C functions...

Comment: @Jester I replaced `mov ecx, [array1+1]` with `lea ecx, [array1+1]`,  but there still exists Segmentation fault...

Comment: You have an extra colon after `section .data:`. That makes the section name `.data:` instead of `.data` and so won't be recognized as a standard section making its attributes wrong (read-only).

Comment: @Jester Oops, my bad. Thx